# Error on multi buffer rendering

Tags: debugging, terminal-emacs, doom, treemacs

I had been using emacs since 5-10 years ago and never had any single problem, I used to use Vanilla emacs with some configurations as Sebastiencs's Sidebar, now I'm using Doom emacs with treemacs. In both (vanilla or doom) happens the below error in which basically the two buffers (the current one and the sidebar) get messy as I navigate through the buffers and for some strange reason the file buffer got printed on the sidebar and viceversa. The situation is worst as I continue navigating through a file. Even though is not with every single file, e.g. some Rust or Golang files are getting me into this error but I have a lot of C libraries (mostly from GNU) in which this is not happening, but happens again for example with the treemacs sidebar and magit buffers.

- Could this be a potential encoding error?
- Could this be a potential missconfiguration or maybe just a bug?

I have no idea and I didn't find useful stuff on Google. Need help here. This began today, my version is
`GNU Emacs 28.1` and my current OS is MacOS Monterey (normally I use it under linux but this is not the case right now) also I'm using iTerm2.

[image: Error]

Comment: It *might* be a terminal issue.  Try a different terminal?  Or try running GUI Emacs -- does that have the same problem?

Comment: I opened the same file (the one of the image above) in both iTerm2 and Alacritty and is consistently failling on iTerm2 but not on Alacritty ... I like a lot more Alacritty + Tmux but the only reason I don't use it under my current system is because of the Meta character which cannot be mapped to esc as in iTerm2.  But yeah that seems to be the problem (till now) I'll be testing some other files. Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about MacOS, but IIRC iTerm2 is its standard terminal?  If so, it certainly seems odd that a Mac build of Emacs would have any difficulty with it.  I don't have much insight into what the specific problem will be, I'm afraid.  Hopefully Alacritty does indeed do the job in the meantime.

Comment: It is not the Apple Standard terminal but the community standard terminal I mean I don't know folks with macOS using the default terminal instead of that, so, it is supposed to be quite stable, even though I have only worked with macos like 2 months so I'm very far from being an expert here. Also seems that I found a hack for the Meta character so finally I can use Alacritty as my main terminal as I used to on linux.

Comment: You're not the only one having iTerm2 issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803319/the-display-is-wrong-when-using-iterm2-screen-emacs-on-macos-monterey